# Print the value of a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
({
    "text1": "item_1",
    "text2": "item_2",
    "text3": "item_3",
    "text4": "item_4"
})
```

How can I print the value of `text2` ?

Do jQuery will be fastest than pure JS ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Comment: JSON cannot start with `(`

Comment: @LuckyChingi, yes but how to load the json? Actually the json is into the variable.

Comment: If you already have the json loaded in a variable the do `variablename.text2`. If it is in string format in the variable then parse it first with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON`)

Comment: @Carotte no framework is faster than pure JavaScript, because they all derive from JavaScript.

Comment: @Carotte if you are declaring the JSON object statically which looks to be the case then, wrap it in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` and or just include in a external JS page. When the browser compiles it runs and will initiate them, then you can call it from wherever as long it's within scope.

Answer (score 1):

Once that object is assigned to a variable (say `foo`) you'd be able to print `text2` value by doing:

```
var foo = {
  "text1": "item_1",
  "text2": "item_2",
  "text3": "item_3",
  "text4": "item_4"
};

console.log(foo.text2);
```

Regarding how faster is JS over jQuery, this is a very simple instruction and there won't be a significant difference between one or the other.

Comment: @Carotte add this to your `<script>` tag.

Comment: @Carotte and yes per this scenario there will be little to no difference in performance. In general however frameworks are slower.

Answer (score 0):

var strJSON = '{
    "text1": "item_1",
    "text2": "item_2",
    "text3": "item_3",
    "text4": "item_4"
}';

var objJSON = eval("(function(){return " + strJSON + ";})()");

alert(objJSON.text2);

Comment: There is `JSON.parse` nowadays (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Answer (score -1):

```
$.getJSON("test.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in console
    console.log(json.text2); //should print item_2 in console   
});
```

pure JS is faster if you know how to write it properly. Jquery add a lot of nice features for developers but it costs CPU and memory.

This example above uses jQuery (hence the $)

Comment: this is assuming your json file that you mentioned is test.json and in the same directory....

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot. Do not why why someone -1 your answer.

Comment: down, because jquery is not necessary for accessing an object

Comment: That wasn't the question. I provided an answer using the technologies he is using and then answered the 2nd question to the best of my ability. I'm well aware jQuery isn't required, I even advocated pure JS. For his needs this would suffice. If the answers are wrong then -1.